# hive history comman not working

Tags: hive

hi I am a basic learner in hadoop hive.$HOME/.hivehistory is not working or let me know where to type that command.I closed my terminal due to some reasons and opened after some time.Now how could I open previous commands history.Please help me.I am unable to sort out.

Answer (score 0):

`.hivehistory` is located under the home directory of the user who invoked the CLI, e.g. -

When invoked with user `cloudera` (which is the user I'm currently using)

```
bash-4.1$ ls -l ~/.hivehistory 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cloudera cloudera 1093 May  6 10:42 /home/cloudera/.hivehistory
```

When invoked with user `hive`

```
bash-4.1$ ls -l ~hive/.hivehistory 
-rw-r--r-- 1 hive hive 20 May  6 10:53 /var/lib/hive/.hivehistory
```

---

Source code: [CliDriver.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/cli/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/cli/CliDriver.java)

```
  private void setupCmdHistory() {
    final String HISTORYFILE = ".hivehistory";
    String historyDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home");
    PersistentHistory history = null;
    try {
      if ((new File(historyDirectory)).exists()) {
        String historyFile = historyDirectory + File.separator + HISTORYFILE;
        history = new FileHistory(new File(historyFile));
        reader.setHistory(history);
      } else {
        System.err.println("WARNING: Directory for Hive history file: " + historyDirectory +
                           " does not exist.   History will not be available during this session.");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("WARNING: Encountered an error while trying to initialize Hive's " +
                         "history file.  History will not be available during this session.");
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```